# tailwindcss-forms plugin / styling forms with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, forms, tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind CSS and stumbled across the [`tailwindcss-forms`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms) plugin.

1. Why exactly do we need that? Does it just provide new classes that I have to apply manually or does it by default apply some classes to forms?
2. Can't I just apply classes from the regular Tailwind CSS to my forms?
3. What's the difference to e.g. [`tailwindcss-custom-forms`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-custom-forms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tailwind CSS is not exactly providing solutions for form elements like Select-tags and co. that work on all major browsers.
2. If you apply those from Tailwind CSS, you may either add your own elements (e.g. arrows) for a Select tag, inputs, and co. or work with CSS. You can also look on how developers solved these issues with examples from [Tailwind Components](https://tailwindcomponents.com/).
3. Tailwind CSS Forms was made to make this possible and it works with Tailwind CSS 2 while Tailwind CSS Custom Form is deprecated.